# Using Kafka java producer send a message: Producer connection to localhost:9092 unsuccessful

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to send a message to Kafka server. the broker list is not include localhost. But when produce invoke the send method, it's has exception: Producer connection to localhost:9092 unsuccessful

```
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

import java.util.Properties;

// create a producer

Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("metadata.broker.list", "192.168.1.203:9092");
props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
props.put("request.required.acks", "1");

ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);

producer = new Producer<String, String>(config);

//sending...
String topic = "data_collect_events";
String message = "_Message_1";
KeyedMessage<String, String> keyedMessage = new KeyedMessage<String, String>(topic, message);
producer.send(keyedMessage);
```

exception:

```
ERROR [main] 2013-07-23 19:27:10,580 kafka.utils.Logging$class: Producer connection to localhost:9092 unsuccessful
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:364)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:356)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:623)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.connect(BlockingChannel.scala:57)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.connect(SyncProducer.scala:146)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.getOrMakeConnection(SyncProducer.scala:161)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:68)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncProducer.scala:101)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:101)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:101)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.kafka$producer$async$DefaultEventHandler$$send(DefaultEventHandler.scala:244)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$dispatchSerializedData$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:107)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$dispatchSerializedData$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:101)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:631)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$$anon$1.foreach(HashTable.scala:161)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:80)
    at enter code herekafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.dispatchSerializedData(DefaultEventHandler.scala:101)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:74)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:32)
```

Answer (score 5):

In kafka 0.8 the broker list is only used for retrieving metadata.
The producer then connects to the broker using the returned metadata info.
The hostname in the metadata depends on the OS setting for the host (see
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-OnEC2%2Cwhycan%27tmyhighlevelconsumersconnecttothebrokers%3F
).

You can set host.name in server.properties. like this

```
host.name=192.168.1.203
```

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you're using Kafka 0.7 with config keys for Kafka 0.8, so

```
props.put("metadata.broker.list", "192.168.1.203:9092");
```

is simply ignored and producer defaults to *localhost:9092* when no broker specified. 
 [You have to use](https://kafka.apache.org/07/configuration.html) `broker.list` rather than `meta.broker.list`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where in the Kafka producer located outside EC2 was not able to resolve internal EC2 IP as expected by a Zookeeper.

I edited the `/etc/hosts` file to add an entry of:
`public-ip` & `internal-ec2-ip` 
for the producer to talk to Kafka broker.